# Can the generic $ax + by + cz = 0$ equation for a plane through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$ be extended to any basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Meaning, if I have a basis $\beta = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$, may I write any plane through the origin in the form $a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3 = 0$, where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Since the $v_i$'s are linearly independent, the only solution to $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 = 0$ is the trivial solution.

Comment: $ax+by+cz=0$ is $n\cdot ((x,y,z)^T-0)=0$. I don't see why $\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{x}=0$ shouldn't work in an arbitrary $\mathbb{R}^3$ basis. However, if the basis is not orthogonal/orthonormal, the resulting dot product will not be so simple, but yes, still in the form $Ax+By+Cz-D=0$ where an arbitrary vector from the plane $\mathbf{x}=xv_1+yv_2+zv_3$, even maybe with $D=0$, I'm not sure.